# Elixir Alias returns "invalid argument for alias, expected a compile time atom or alias, got: "

Tags: elixir

I created a new project using mix and I'm trying alias, this is my simple code:

```
defmodule MyModule do
  alias IO.puts
  def hello do
    IO.puts(:world)
  end
end
```

but it's returning to me this error:
    `invalid argument for alias, expected a compile time atom or alias, got: IO.puts()`

I've also tried:

```
alias IO.puts, as: puts
alias IO.puts, as: puts()
alias IO.puts(), as: puts
```

How can I solve this error and why it's happening given that I'm following the documentation for alias!

Comment: `alias` just helps you in using shortening the module names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in the docs, [**`Alias`**](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#alias/2) allows you to set up aliases for any given **module name**.
The purpose of `alias` is aliasing module names. What you are looking for is **`import`**, which allows you to use function names without their full module name.

If I understand what you want to do correctly, you would want to use `import IO`, or more specifically, `import IO, only: [puts: 2]`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to `alias` anything. Just

```
defmodule MyModule do
  def hello do
    IO.puts(:world)
  end
end
```

By the way, `alias` expects a module as the first argument, not a function.